# Finding a position on a helix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

$r(t)$ is defined as follows:

$r(t) = (12\sin(t))$ ***i*** $-(12\cos(t))$ ***j*** + 5t ***k***

I'm asked to find the position on the helix (above) which is located at arc-length distance of $-13\pi$ units along the helical curve from initial position  $r_{0}=(0,-12,0)$

I would appreciate any help with this question as I don't even know how to approach it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arclength formula for a parametrized curve $\alpha:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ between time $t_1$ and $t_2$ is given by $\displaystyle \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{ \sum_{i = 1}^n \left( \frac{dx_i}{dt} \right)^2} \ dt$.

For this scenario, you can check that the starting position corresponds to $t_1=0$.  Therefore, we wish to solve the following equation for $t_2$:

$$\int_0^{t_2} \sqrt{ (12 \cos(t))^2 + (12 \sin(t))^2 + 5^2 } \ dt = -13 \pi $$

A choice trig identity makes this integral easy.

---

The "negative" arclength indicates we're "going in reverse" relative to the starting position.  In other words, $t_2< 0$.  You can switch the bounds of integration and change $-13 \pi$ to $13 \pi$ in order to reflect this so that the above equation looks more intuitive.

Comment: Wait, so the question is asking to calculate the arclength ?

Comment: Or the position of the end point of the arclength?

Comment: The position of the end point.  The unknown in this arclength formula is the $t_2$.  When you find that $t_2$, you can plug it into the parametrization of the helix to find the endpoint you're looking for.

Comment: We're using the arclength formula since the clue we're given *is* the arclength between $(0, -12, 0)$ and the point at time $t_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You are given the terminal point $r(t_0=0)$. You just need to find a $t_1$ such that:

$$\int_{t_1}^0 \|\vec{r}'(t)\|\ dt = 13\pi$$

Here $\vec{r}'(t) = \langle 12 \cos t, 12 \sin t, 5 \rangle \Rightarrow \|\vec{r}'(t)\| = \sqrt{12^2 \cos^2t+ 12^2 \sin^2t + 25} = \sqrt{169} = 13$

$$\int_{t_1}^0 \|\vec{r}'(t)\|  \ dt = \int_{t_1}^0 13 \ dt = -13t_1$$

Hence, if you take $t_1 = \pi$ then you are done i.e $r(\pi)$ is the desired point.

Comment: Perfect, nice explanation thanks!

Comment: I would just like to point out that this is exactly what @Kaj Hansen did. He just wanted to work through the details. It seemed as though something was still not clicking, so at least with this, you have an example of how to proceed with these problems in general, so try another.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the input nonetheless.